# How do I Add Text to a form pull

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make an API Fetch from a Form Input (The Search bar of my site), I Want to add Text to whatever was inputted to the Text Field and then send it trough to be pulled.

```
<form id="SearchBoxMainNav" style="display: flex;">
    <input class="nav-button" type="submit" name="search" value="" >
    <input id="SearchTerm" type="search" class="search" name="search" value="" placeholder="I Draw...!" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

Java Script

```
const apiUrl = 'https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php';

SearchBoxMainNav.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData(SearchBoxMainNav);
const formDataSerialized = Object.fromEntries(formData);
const jsonObject = { ...formDataSerialized};
console.log(formDataSerialized, "formDataSerialized");

try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify("fname" + jsonObject),
        Headers: {
            'Contnent-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
} catch(event) {
    console.error(event)
    alert("there was an Error")
}

});
```

so what I Would like to do is as they submit it Text is added to the Front and then It goes trough the whole javascript Prosccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the text with `jsonObject.search`, not `jsonObject`.

`Object.fromEntries()` returns a new object, there's no need to duplicate it with `{...formDataSerialized}`

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php';

SearchBoxMainNav.addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(SearchBoxMainNav);
  const jsonObject = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  jsonObject.search = 'fname ' + jsonObject.search;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
      Headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
  } catch (event) {
    console.error(event)
    alert("there was an Error")
  }

});
```